# What exactly is crt1.3.1.o

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, clang

I'm using xcode 4.5 My Base SDK is 6.0 and my deployment target is 5.1. When I try to build for release or profiling I get this little gem of an error.

```
ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.3.1.o for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now....

I have seen this message posted on stackoverflow but Im still none the wiser.

What exactly is this crt1.2.1.o thats causing all the fuss?
Can I modify it somehow to kill my error?
And finally it has been suggested that I simply set build for active architectures only. What are the implications of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crt1.3.1.o file contains the startup code for the C runtime library. This initializes the runtime, calls global initializers and finally calls the `main` function.

Something must be amiss with your project settings. You are compiling for armv7s as well, but the libraries are being linked from the iOS 5.1 SDK which doesn't support the armv7s architecture yet.

Comment: do you reckon its safe enough to just set build for active architectures only to 'yes' ?

Comment: It’s hard to tell without knowing what the underlying problem is, and what device you have connected.  I’d first suggest looking at both the Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, I removed armv7s from valid architectures in build settings and left only armv7, after that I could archive my project

Comment: I pretty much did the same. I'm just concerned about any possible implications of doing this